# Array Foreach Confusion

Tags: javascript

How to get each tag of tags property?

```
let array = [
   {name: "A", tags: ["a", "b"]}, 
   {name: "B", tags: ["a", "b", "c"]}
]

array.forEach(arr => {
   arr.tags.forEach(tag => {
       let str = `${arr.name} : ${tag}`;
       console.log(str);

       // result:
       // A : a
       // A : b
       // B : a
       // B : b
       // B : c
   })
})
```

But I want something like this

```
       // result:
       // A : <span>a</span> <span>b</span>
       // B : <span>a</span> <span>a</span> <span>c</span>
```

Sorry, my english is bad, hope you can understand what is my question

Comment: `arr.tags` is an array - if you want to access inside it, you can access it with `arr.tags[n]`

Comment: `tags` is an array such as `array` (not the best name...). To get every element of `array` you use `.forEach()`. Simply do the same with `.tags`

Comment: Do you want to iterate all tags, from name A and from name B, or just a specific one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let array = [
   {name: "A", tags: ["a", "b"]}, 
   {name: "B", tags: ["a", "b", "c"]}
]

array.forEach(function(arr){
   var element = arr.name + " : ";
   arr.tags.forEach(function(tag){
       element = element + ('<span>'+tag+'</span>');
   });
   console.log(element);
});
```